# How to copy all files from a directory and its subdirectories to another dir?

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp

I have a `/dir1`, the structure is:

```
./aaa.txt
./bbb.jpg
./subdir1/cccc.doc
./subdir1/eeee.txt
./subdir2/dddd.xls
./subdir2/ffff.jpg
```

I want to copy all `.txt` and `.jpg` in `/dir1` and its subdirectories to `/dir2`.

By using `cp -r /dir1/* /dir2`, it copies all files and its structure to `/dir2`.

By using `cp -r /dir1/*.jpg /dir2` and `cp -r /dir1/*.txt /dir2`, it doesn't copy the `.jpg` and `.txt` files in the subdirectories.

By using

```
for FILE in `find`
do
  cp -f $FILE /dir1/
done
```

it can copy all files in dir and subdirectories to the destination, but I cannot filter the file type.

Is there another way that can achieve what I want?

Comment: ‘*but I cannot filter the file type*’ Sure you can, `find` is great at that.

Comment: I used `man find`, it shows me `-type f` related, but I see is `f      regular file`, it didn't tell me how to combine it with `-name`.  What's the right way to read a manual?

Comment: `man find` is a great way to read a manual. And to combine `-type` and `-name` just put one after the other: `find . -type f -name '*.jpg'`

Comment: The [GNU findutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) is actually quite readable (and extensive: clocks in at 115 pages in the PS version).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find` to get the desired source files, and then use `cp` within the `-exec` predicate of `find` to copy the files to the desired destination. With GNU `cp`:

```
find /dir1/ -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec cp -t /dir2/ {} +
```

POSIX-ly:

```
find /dir1/ -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.jpg' \) -exec cp {} /dir2/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `globstar`<sup>1</sup> and `extglob` shell options:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob
cp dir1/**/*.@(txt|jpg) dir2
```

The `**/` expression matches zero or more directories or subdirectories, so you get files from the whole subtree of `dir1`; `@(txt|jpg)` is an extended pattern that matches either `txt` or `jpg`.

For the somewhat unlikely case that there are no `.jpg` and `.txt` files in any of `dir1`, but a file called `*.@(txt|jpg)` in a subdirectory of `dir1` called `**`, you may also want to set the `failglob` shell option so the command is not executed if the glob doesn't match anything – instead of copying the unlikely file.

---

<sup>1</sup> `globstar` was added in Bash 4.0 and is thus not available for the Bash that comes standard with Mac OS (3.2).

Comment: what does the 1st statement do?  I tried to `man set`, it tells me there's not manual for `set`.  I executed your statement, it tells me `set -s` is invalid.